Symfony/EasyAdmin: how to access entity when rendering embedded form
I'm using Symfony 6.4 and EasyAdmin 4.10
I'm rendering a form including embedded forms for entities included in the main entity (A Client class that includes several Videos and Playlists).
I'm creating my backend so we only access the Client edition page, and all the other elements are edited inside the it as CollectionFields.
I'd like to customize the Crud editor for Playlists so some of its fields are filtered depending on the actual playlist that is being edited. I've already achieved this in the Client CRUD controlller class by using $this->getContext()->getEntity()->getInstance()
However, this seems not to be possible, as I cannot find the way to access the Entity corresponding to the Playlist, as $this->getContext()->getEntity()->getInstance() always returns a Client, not a Playlist.
Is there any way to achieve this?
